# Container Implementation

Tags: rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I'm currently working on a project where users will upload projects, but others users will be able to clone those projects (think github-esque).

Now my initial idea is create a container for each project, making it easy to clone them. Though I will still store a reference to each file & it's location in the database.

Would creating a container for each project be the best option, or should I stick to a container per user? I know the file amount limits are huge in the containers, but I feel my initial plan would scale better.

Thoughts people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just personal opinion as I am currently also using rackspace cloud in my project. I think that creating one container for each users will be still good option since you can copy, move object inside container.

And also by creating container for each user you can easily get current size object, container of users so that you can know what current free space they have without using additional calculation of it.